# How to have a field with a select list widget and custom list entries?

Tags: 7, nodes

In my content type there is a text field that is set using a list (combobox).

When adding new content, the list is displayed with static elements.

I would like to query an external site when the user adds content (or edits the page) and then build the list from the query result. The user can then select from these elements.

Is that possible?

Comment: This is for Drupal 8 or 7?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer sorry I missed that. I am currently using Drupal 7 but a solution for Drupal 8 is also interesting because I plan to migrate in the coming month.

Comment: Well is possible for Drupal 7. You only need to search now.  The concept is the same.

Answer (score 3):

**For Drupal 8**

Yes, is possible, but you will need to [implement your own field type](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-type).

You should take a look into the [Country](https://www.drupal.org/project/country) module as you will need to implement the [OptionsProviderInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21OptionsProviderInterface.php/interface/OptionsProviderInterface/8.2.x) interface.

In the [getPossibleOptions](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/country/tree/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/CountryItem.php#n158) method, you will query the external site and get the possible options for your field.

**For Drupal 7**

You can always take a look [inside](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/field_example?h=7.x-1.x) the [Examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) even for Drupal 8 you will find a very useful boilerplate code for your projects. If you want to check another example just go to the [Countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) module.

Comment: That looks very good - thanks. However it appears that this API is new to D8 right? The D7 API looks very different for custom fields. Do you think this approach is possible in D7 as well?

Comment: @testalino I added an example for Drupal 7